# Java : I want to get the line number of the line where output stream has written the data in a file

Tags: java

I am trying to write some data to file using Buffered Writer. I have requirement to create an index file with some time stamp and line number. For this I require the line number where the output stream had written.

Can you please suggest some method to achieve this

Comment: You should post what you have tried. People will not just do all of the work for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I searched java i/o package and was unable to find a specific function

Answer (score 2):

Increment a counter whenever you write a line to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you area appending to file than go till eof counting number of line and then count the number of lines after the output stream is dumping its data in file.
If you are in unix you can easily use wc command from java before and after ouput stream is done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you may be looking for is your own custom implementation of the `BufferedWriter` class which can use `java.util.logging` or log4j to write a line to your index file every time a newline is encountered in the `write` methods.

Alternatively, you could wrap your `BufferedWriter` in a custom `PrintWriter` class and only use the `println` methods for your index file logging.